# Receive data from other apps using WebIntent in Ionic 4 or 5

Tags: ionic-framework, broadcastreceiver, ionic4, start-activity, webintents

ionic plugin add https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent --save
the above plugin added to my ionic app after that, I am unable to build the apk in ionic framework and please suggest me how to receive data from other apps using WebIntent using Ionic Framework

Answer (score 0):

install

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/web-intent@4
```

since the latest version of the webintent not working

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.